# More Actions menu missing in Shoreditch

Tags: shoreditch

I'm finding the More actions link that appears at the righthand end of CiviCRM displays to be missing in Shoreditch. Presumably this is not by design? Some actions appear to only be accessible through that menu.

[image: Picture of the action column in the CiviCRM default theme]
[image: Picture of the action column in Shoreditch]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version from https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/releases (1.0.0-beta.2) has the fix included for the above problem. Pls upgrade.

Comment: Ah, thank you, yes that fixed it. The Shoreditch page in the extensions directory is still showing beta 1 as the most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

try adding below line in your theme css file

```
.crm-container span.btn-slide {
    display: unset !important;
}
```

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: In the Drupal theme? Or editing one of the Shoreditch files?

Comment: In Drupal theme, incase you dont have access to your theme file than you can add it in a block and place it in a footer on all civicrm pages.